# How to design an UI framework for multiple web applications with the same layout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, frameworks, cdn

I'm trying to design an ui framework for multiple web applications but having trouble designing the infrastructure for our situation:

- 7 (or more) separated web applications build with asp.net mvc
- Some web applications on internal servers, some hosted
- All with the same basic css/images/javascript (shared components each application can use)
- Every application has some unique css and javascript
- Every application has its own TFS branch and solution
- Every application has its own release management (monthly/yearly/etc.)

What I want to achieve:

- Fix UI bugs once and not for all applications
- Consistent UI for all applications
- Don't bother the other developers with UI stuff

What would be a smart infrastructure?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the difficulty in sharing non-compiled code between web projects is mostly a source control one. We use an internal NuGet server to share compiled code, but this doesn't work very well for non-compiled code. For this stuff (HTML, sripts, content) I find it's easiest to keep all common components of the framework in a single hierarchy that can be stored as an independent project or submodule in whatever source control system you use, e.g.

```
/myframework/scripts
/myframework/styles
/myframework/images
```

If "myframework" is managed as a submodule, you should be able to maintain it independently of the projects you include it in. This is straightforward with git and svn.

Your application-specific scripts and content can be kept in whatever normal hierarchy you like as usual, e.g.

```
/scripts
/styles
/images
```

You might also look at how popular front-end frameworks are set up in their default configuration. For example, [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) provides a set of scripts, styles and content templates. Everything is stored under folders `Content` and `Javascripts` by default,  and they counsel that you don't change their style sheet but rather override styles in a separate style sheet for anything custom. This keeps you safe from changes to the shared framework. Applying a similar policy to your own internal framework seems sensible.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using NuGet to distribute the css/js/images to all the different projects. The global ui has its own team project with automated nuget package creation to our internal nuget server.